# Disabling JQDialog Resize

Tags: jquery

For some reason I can't find any documentation in disabling the resize functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, JQDialog [has a resizable option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-resizable)